# What's meaning of this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
url = (url.match(/^([^#]+)/)||[])[1];

iframeSrc: /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:false' : 'about:blank'
```

What's meanning of the code above, I found it in the source of  jquery.form.js.

Comment: Something with and iframe where everything after the # in a url will be removed

Comment: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F%5E%28%5B%5E%23%5D%2B%29%2F

Comment: The first line removes the part of an url that is an "anchor", which is a way of telling not only which page you want to navigate to, but where on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line removes the hash portion of a given URL string.

The second line, which I assume is in the middle of an object definition somewhere (or the : would be a syntax error), looks at the URL of the current page, checks if it's HTTPS, and uses a different URL for some dynamic iFrame if it is. Presumably there are security reasons why `javascript:false` would be better for an iFrame than `about:blank` on an HTTPS page.

Comment: Thank you very much.The first line removes the hash portion of a given URL string. But I still don't understand the meanning of "||[]" and "[1]". TT

Comment: If .match fails to match, it returns a falsy value (can't remember offhand if it's false, null or undefined). So ||[] defaults to an empty array instead, allowing [1] to access the match string, or get undefined. If you tried to call false[1] you'd get an error.